# How can send the telegram bot location to users?

Tags: bots, telegram

I want to send location of the bot to users, I very searched about it in google , but i find just this case"send location of users to the bot" I want versa case that mean:"send location of the bot to the users".
this is my idea: the owner of the bot is a driver who that want to share his location with the users of the bot,in the bot i put a button,when the users click on that button, the bot tell them location of driver.the location of bot is variable and it isn't constant

Comment: location of bot? you mean location of telegram servers? bot doesn't have Gps or latitude and doesn't travel, you could send any selectiv location from bot to user

Comment: my mean is location of who that has the bot, not users,the owner of the bot.

Comment: @samira think of telegram and telegram bot as a messaging method for your application (like sms). In your case, you need to write an app which gets the location from iOS or android, and then send that location to some user (via sms, telegram or any other messaging system). Hope this helps to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Sample request for send location from Bot to user with URL:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot[botToken]/sendlocation?chat_id=[UserID]&latitude=51.6680&longitude=32.6546
```

Requirement for execute URL:

[botToken], e.g:399684XXX:AAH_NiVFtLXVmh4XXX-XXXEZo3yO6XXX

[UserID], e.g:64326XX

latitude , e.g:51.6680
longitude, e.g:32.6546

Comment: thank you.this request requires the latitude and longitude,but i dont have them, can i get these data from GPS of phone?

Comment: You can get latitude and longitude from google map and it's another problem i suggest, description your idea for get good hand .

Comment: @samira , If my answer is helpful and answer of your question Please set answer (give the tick answer) , Thanks

Comment: my idea: the owner of the bot is a driver who that want to share his location with the users of the bot,in the bot i put a button,when the users click on that button, the bot tell them location of driver.the location of bot is variable and it isn't constant so i cant get latitude and longitude from google map

Comment: @samira You need use a program language for Implementation this idea with bot of telegram. for example u can use c# language . i suggest you open new topic(ask new question) about your idea as a question and give me link and i will help you there and if you get answer of first question please set tick of answer .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sendVenue](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvenue) or [sendLocation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendlocation) method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

use `sendLocation` and not a web request to telegram api, to get the longitude and latitude you can use `messageEventArgs.Message.Location.Latitude` and `messageEventArgs.Message.Location.Longitude` with telegram c# bot api